# Xamarin app crashes on startup on device, works fine in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Would appreciate any suggestions, using SDK6.1 with Xcode 5 on OS 10.8

The app crashes right after the splash and does not get to the debugger at all. this happens on the TestFlight released version as well. Tried on another computer with same results. Even tried to create a new sample Monotouch app and same results.

```
Jan 28 15:25:59 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Error>:     __hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x14d832a0     pthread_self=0x4116000
Jan 28 15:25:59 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: mux-ad(eng)::setLinkQualityMetricGated: Setting link quality metric to 50
Jan 28 15:26:00 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[695] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C15EE9BA-4693-432B-899A-90340F54664E (sandbox)
Jan 28 15:26:00 maimonphone networkd[78] <Warning>: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.pacealert.app
Jan 28 15:26:00 maimonphone PaceAlert[695] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Added IP to look for MonoDevelop: 192.168.45.129
Jan 28 15:26:00 maimonphone PaceAlert[695] <Warning>: MonoTouch: MonoDevelop Port: 10000 Transport: WiFi
Jan 28 15:26:02 maimonphone PaceAlert[695] <Warning>: The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
Jan 28 15:26:02 maimonphone PaceAlert[695] <Warning>: It should have been installed in the `/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
Jan 28 15:26:02 maimonphone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x1257][695]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x1257]) Exited with code: 1
Jan 28 15:26:02 maimonphone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x1257]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x1257]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483645 seconds
Jan 28 15:26:02 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x1257]' exited abnormally with exit status 1
```

It says something about a missing file  but I am pretty sure it is there :-(

------ some more from the console ----
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone mobile_installation_proxy[261] : LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone mobile_installation_proxy[261] : LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone installd[225] : 0x201000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/PaceAlert.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone installd[225] : 0x201000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.pacealert.app
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : Killing com.pacealert.app for termination assertion
    Jan 28 16:30:12 maimonphone installd[225] : 0x201000 install_application: Performing developer delta patch
    Jan 28 16:30:14 maimonphone installd[225] : 0x201000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.12s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 2.46s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 2.59s
    Jan 28 16:30:14 maimonphone lsd[221] : LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
    Jan 28 16:30:15 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: nike-ipod is static and will never generate a notification
    Jan 28 16:30:15 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
    Jan 28 16:30:15 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: magnetometer is static and will never generate a notification
    Jan 28 16:30:15 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a notification
    Jan 28 16:30:15 maimonphone SpringBoard[34] : libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
    Jan 28 16:30:19 maimonphone MobileStorageMounter[770] : 0x3d5c218c digest_disk_image: Could not open /var/run/mobile_image_mounter/7MyG0L.dmg: No such file or directory
    Jan 28 16:30:19 maimonphone MobileStorageMounter[770] : 0x3d5c218c reload_mount_map: /Developer - could not create digest
    Jan 28 16:30:19 maimonphone mobile_storage_proxy[769] : 0x3d5c218c handle_lookup_image: Entry 2 of 4 did not have a digest

```
Jan 28 16:30:20 maimonphone MobileStorageMounter[770] <Error>: 0x3d5c218c handle_mount_disk_image: A disk image of type Developer is already mounted
Jan 28 16:30:20 maimonphone mobile_storage_proxy[769] <Error>: MobileStorageMount:355 Could not extract mount path from response message
Jan 28 16:30:20 maimonphone mobile_storage_proxy[769] <Error>: 0x3d5c218c handle_mount_image: Could not mount the disk image
Jan 28 16:30:20 maimonphone mobile_storage_proxy[769] <Error>: 0x3d5c218c main: Could not mount the image

Jan 28 16:30:23 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[771] <Warning>: debugserver-300.2 for armv7.
Jan 28 16:30:23 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[771] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Jan 28 16:30:25 maimonphone locationd[53] <Warning>: NStatManagerHandleSrcCounts:1549 couldn't find NStatSourceRef for 5522
Jan 28 16:30:25 maimonphone locationd[53] <Warning>: NStatManagerHandleSrcDescriptor:1214 update descriptor for invalid source
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: debugserver-300.2 for armv7.
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: About to launch process for bundle ID: com.pacealert.app
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Error>: __hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x14d832a0 pthread_self=0x433d000
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.455532]: ATJManager: setting ask-to-join interaction mode to Interactive
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.456357]: ATJManager: no entries to purge
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.456922]: Device is UNLOCKED
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.457431]: Ignoring lock state
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.457943]: problematic networks =  and potentially problematic networks =
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.458562]: Unblacklisting
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.463413]: No change in Background Scan candidates. Skip re-programming Background Scan
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.509190]: Already connected to MY_NETWORK.
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.510816]: Device display is ON
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612226.513297]: Already connected to MY_NETWORK.
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x68a)
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
Jan 28 16:30:26 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
Jan 28 16:30:28 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612228.766440]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd networkd
Jan 28 16:30:28 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612228.767826]: Already connected to MY_NETWORK.
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[773] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/C15EE9BA-4693-432B-899A-90340F54664E (sandbox)
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone networkd[78] <Warning>: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.pacealert.app
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: In completion handler, got pid for bundle id, pid: 773.
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: Got a connection, launched process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver.

Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0304/060b]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x0305, tid = 0x2503, signal = -1) err = Invalid argument (0x00000016)
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: 2 +0.053023 sec [0304/1c0b]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x2849ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[771] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0303/060b]: error: ::read ( 6, 0x27da5dcc, 1024 ) => 0 err = Function not implemented (0x0000004e)
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[771] <Warning>: Exiting.
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone mobile_installation_proxy[261] <Error>: 0x19c7000 handle_connection: Could not receive request from host.
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone mobile_installation_proxy[261] <Error>: 0x181000 handle_connection: Could not receive request from host.
Jan 28 16:30:29 maimonphone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[772] <Warning>: Exiting.
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Added IP to look for MonoDevelop: 192.168.45.129
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: MonoDevelop Port: 10000 Transport: USB
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Successfully received USB connection from MonoDevelop on port 10000, fd: 5
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Processing: 'start debugger: sdb'
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Successfully received USB connection from MonoDevelop on port 10000, fd: 6
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Processing: 'connect output'
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Debugger loaded with custom transport (fd: 5)
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Successfully received USB connection from MonoDevelop on port 10000, fd: 7
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: MonoTouch: Processing: 'start profiler: no'
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone PaceAlert[773] <Warning>: It should have been installed in the `/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x22ee][773]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x22ee]) Exited with code: 1
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x22ee]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x22ee]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483646 seconds
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.pacealert.app[0x22ee]' exited abnormally with exit status 1
Jan 28 16:30:30 maimonphone wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[412612230.488133]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd networkd
```

### Jan 28 16:30:32 maimonphone backboardd[28] : __hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x14d832a0 pthread_self=0x433d000

Comment: could you paste the full crash log? you can find it by using the Organizer in Xcode.

Comment: this is everything that is added to the log since launching the app. there is a LOT of stuff before. but every time I try launch I get this part.

Comment: Also noticed on the configuration that simulator has SDK6.0 and SDK7.0 while the iphone has 6.1 and 7.0 = not sure how that happened or if it related

Comment: Xcode 5 ships with several simulator SDK (e.g. 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0) but only **one** SDK for devices (7.0). Along with the (symbolicated) crash report asked (by Stephan) a full build log (included extra `-v -v -v -v`) could give more clues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unbelievable... the solution was to install the **Xcode command line tools**.

This is (easily!) done from the Xcode->Preference->Downloads menu.

I have spent hours on this today, I hope this helps some other poor fellow.

Comment: For those that might think this isn't your issue, try it anyway. Debugging was working for me the previous day, but then broke the next. I didn't uninstall or reinstall Xcode, but when I went into the Downloads center, the Command Line tools were not installed. Not sure what uninstalled them, but this fixed my issue.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me. I had the exact same issue where the app crash after splash screen either in debug or testflight build on device but worked on simulator. My logs are almost the same as the above. Installing command line tools fixed it.

Comment: A million thank yous. Just had the same problem on Xcode 61.1/Yosemite and spent hours trying to solve it. Was working a few days ago, then just broke for no apparent reason. Installing the command line tools as suggested here worked, but they didn't actually show for me in the downloads center in Xcode. I had to run a terminal command to install them (xcode-select --install).

I am so sick of this stuff with Xamarin. Either all the tooling runs so slowly you think it's broken, it is just broken when it worked yesterday (using VS integration anyway - I don't use XS).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my problem was actually something else. This will happen if your app 'takes too long to start'. I was kind of aware of this, but my app had always started fine previously and I didn't realise this was the issue.

It seems I had turned on 'break on all exceptions' and a number of components I am now using (such as Xamarin Insights, the Initialize method) throw exceptions internally which cause the debugger to break (even though you can continue from the harmless exception).

The process of capturing the exceptions and marshalling them back to VS can take quite a while (seconds sometimes), and in my case two or three of these on start-up was enough to have iOS kill the app process for misbehaving. I never actually saw the errors because the process terminated too soon for the data to come back to VS, so I didn't know what was going on.

Turning off break on all exceptions, at least until after the app starts, works around this.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It is more of an opinion/comment.